# How to compare two datetime and find minutes

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select, time

I want compare two DateTime and find minutes in SQL

**Example :**

```
 1. Date 1= 10/22/2014 20:00:00.000
 2. Date 2= 10/22/2014 23:00:00.000
```

Then I want the output like this:
**180 minutes**

Comment: i can not any idea to how to do this

Comment: try to google for Date functions in mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
your exmple

SELECT TIMEDIFF('2014-10-22 23:00:00.000','2014-10-22 20:00:00.000')

OR

SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '2014-10-22 20:00:00', '2014-10-22 23:00:00')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [**TIMESTAMPDIFF**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) function:

Try this:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '2014-10-22 20:00:00', '2014-10-22 23:00:00');
```

Comment: it's like that :
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2014-10-22 20:00:00', '2014-10-22 23:00:00');

because TIMESTAMPDIFF is not a recognized built-in function name.